# Use different properties files during Gradle release/debug builds

Tags: java, gradle

I am using Gradle as the build tool and the properties are stored in src/main/resources/myproject.properties. Some example of the properties include:

```
# Mail server properties
mail.server.url = http://mailserver.example.com
mail.server.username = username
mail.server.password = password

# Server url
app.server.url = http://myserver.mydomain.com
```

During development, the properties have different values from the production servers. Right now, we replace the values before deploying it to the production server. Is there a better way for us to specify that the properties should come from myproject-debug.properties during development, myproject-release.properties during release, myproject-qa during testing?

Comment: As per my understanding you are maintaining different properties file viz -QA.properties,-prod.properties,-debug.properties.Is it?well if you are doing this I would say this is a better approach.Since in your code you can call different .prop file based on your env?Let me know if my understanding is not right.

Comment: @ManishSingh - that is the goal. Instead of checking if the deployment is QA, prod, or on dev machine, I think it makes sense to figure that out during packaging and copy the QA, dev, release properties file to the one loaded in the code.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing production settings in the codebase but rather injecting them using environment variables or command-line parameters; see http://12factor.net/.